# how to find files in subdirs with wildcards

Tags: powershell, batch-file, appveyor

I'd like to find all locations of a given file in a subdirectory, where the subdirectory can contain wildcards.

On un*x, I would use something like:

```
find ba* -type f -name "foo" -exec dirname {}
```

Unfortunatly, I need to do this on Windows, using BAT or PowerShell (I don't really care, but the little I know about scripting in W32 is about BAT)

So far I've come up with

```
FOR /R bar %f IN (foo*) DO @echo %~pf
```

but this doesn't allow for wildcards in the directory argument, e.g. <strike>`FOR /R ba* %f IN (foo*) DO @echo %~pf`</strike> is invalid.

So i tried nested loops:

```
FOR /D %d IN (ba*) DO FOR /R bar %f %d IN (foo*) DO @echo %~pf
```

but this only gives me an error, that *%f cannot be used syntactically at this place* (in German: *"%f" kann syntaktisch nicht an dieser Stelle verwendet werden*).

### background

The actual problem I'm trying to solve is this:

In [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#mingw-msys-cygwin) the MinGW installations are buried in some cryptic directories like `C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-6.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev1`.
instead of specifying these cryptic paths (which are most likely fragile with regard to upgrades of the appveyor images) verbatim, I thought of only specifying something like `*x86_64-6.3.*` in my CI-configuration, then let the CI-script search for the path of a required binary (e.g. `mingw64-make.exe`) and automatically add that to my `PATH`.
In the case of multiple matches, I guess I'd just use any one (e.g. the first or last) of the found paths.

e.g. something like:

```
bash$ MINGW_DIR=$(find /c/mingw-w64/${pattern} -type f -name "mingw64-make.exe" -exec dirname {} | tail -1)
```

resp:

```
cmd> FOR /D %d IN (%pattern%) DO FOR /R bar %f %d IN (mingw64-make.*) DO @set %MINGW_DIR%=%~pf
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with PowerShell?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart my feeble attempts are in BAT but I'd be happy to use a PS solution if somebody could point me into the right direction. (and i suspect that PS would have better tools than plain BAT for such a task)

Comment: Yes, I definitely recommend PowerShell, as it's superior to cmd.exe in nearly every conceivable way. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Example of how to locate a file in a subdirectory and add that subdirectory to the current session's path (PowerShell):

```
$executablePath = Get-ChildItem -Filter mingw64-make.exe -File -Recurse |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName
if ( $executablePath ) {
  if ( $env:Path[$env:Path.Length - 1] -ne ";" ) {
    $env:Path += ";"
  }
  $env:Path += $executablePath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way you could do this with Batch is to use the findstr command.

Example in a batch file:

```
@echo
findstr /i /s /C:"random" *.*
pause
```

`/i` makes the search case-insensitive

`/s` means search in sub-directories

`C/:` means search this specific string

The output will be in the form:

`path`:::`the text containing the string [which may be the whole file]`

You can also combine `dir`and `findstr`like so:

```
for /f "delims=." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D ^| findstr /i /s /C:"random" *.bat') do (
    echo "%%a"
    pause
    )
```

The above will recursively go through your root directory and print out where each file [hit space to continue as pause does what it says on the tin]

You can replace the `echo %%a` with `SET PATH=%PATH%;%%a`to add the paths found in `findstr` to the environment path

`"delims=."` will use the extension period as the cut of for printing/matching. Without it you would get partial file names.

`dir /b /a-d` means it will print out the current directory in bare format, but not folders.

[These examples are designed for batch files]

Hope it helps!